# Selenium script throws intermittent 'UnreachableBrowserException' (Selenium : 3.12.0 , 3.13.0)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While debugging one of my selenium script , I was getting intermittent `org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException` . To debug it further , I wrote a code to catch `WebDriverException` (try/catch) & take screenshot whenever script meets `WebDriverException` .

**Here I am surprised to see that screenshot is actually being taken even afer getting `UnreachableBrowserException`.**

Doesn't `UnreachableBrowserException` means that session is not accessible and hence it should be invalidated . So any action performed on webdriver object of that invalidated session should throw `WebDriverException`.

Correct me if I am wrong & ***please explain the above miracle (screenshot capturing works even after getting `UnreachableBrowserException`)***

*For Analysis purpose , I am attaching stacktrace here*

See here I am getting `UnreachableBrowserException` when trying to get current url of browser , however screenshot capturing works and I can see screenshot being saved at location

```
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'mymachine', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c57:d76e:b55f:37ce%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.36.540469 (1881fd7f864150..., userDataDir: /var/folders/ym/dtyc5vz9785...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.99, webStorageEnabled: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: f4748ff254f6fe0418a37e3ab40...}
Session ID: f4748ff254f6fe0418a37e3ab40c3604
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:564)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getCurrentUrl(RemoteWebDriver.java:281)
    at getCurrentURL(MyDriverBot.java:1616)
    at Capture.main(Capture.java:31)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:212)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 10 more
19:25:43.232 [Capture][captureScreenShotOnDashboardException] - Start Capturing screenshot (in case of exception is found
19:25:43.233 [Capture][takeDashboardScreenshot] - Screenshot will be kept at location : /Users/myuserName/result/myException.png
19:25:44.084 [Capture][captureScreenShotOnDashboardException] - End Capturing dashboard (in case of dashboard exception is found
```

Update
It is indeed a genuine issue , hence filed an issue on selenium github

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6170

Update 2 
This is now fixed in selenium - 3.14 version

Comment: I think, issue with the page timeout, try to increase the page timeout. It would help.

Comment: Well my page has already been loaded and I have already fetched some elements using findElements . I don't know why it failed when trying to fetch currenturl of browser . I updated selenium to use latest 3.13 version and latest chrome driver , however I am still facing this issue .

Comment: Share your code, maybe that would help to understand better.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in helping me my friend . Well as far as code is concerned , I have to write a new code , since the code , with which this problem happens lies beneth so many layers in my framework . So I probably have to find a way to produce clean alternative code to show this problem . Moreover as I said issue is happening randomly , which may make my job more difficult to produce clean reproducible code (however I will try)

Comment: One more thing , since I am dam sure that there is not at all an issue with my code , I am speculating 'OKHTTP' (new http client integrated with selenium from 3.9) as a culprit . Looking through this link (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/3GktwJCmmVM) , I am gonna try an alternative mentioned here (forcing webdriver to use apache instead of okhttp) . This seems to be promising

Answer (score 0):

Indeed , it was an issue with 'OKHTTP' , I tried following 2 things to confirm this

1) Added `System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "apache");` to force selenium to use 'apache' instead of 'okhttp' in selenium v3.13 . It worked , I didn't get above random `UnreachableBrowserException` exception (tested it for 2/3 times) , however execution (in terms of identifying elements) was so slow (I don't know why)

2) I downgraded selenium version to use 3.8.1 (from 3.13) & restarted my machine . Built my gradle project again & executed code 2/3 times . Again I wasn't getting above `UnreachableBrowserException` exception.

Above things concludes that it seems that 'okhttp' has some issue . As of now I have migrated to selenium 3.8.1 & things are working fine